# Laravel Dusk-Example Test Results in Risky Test, Skipped

Tags: testing, skip, laravel-dusk

I've just started using TDD and Dusk to my coding routine.

After a clean install of Laravel and Dusk, I run `php artisan dusk` and the Example test returns the following:

```
PHPUnit 7.5.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

R                                           1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 215 ms, Memory: 16.00MB

There was 1 risky test:

1) Tests\Browser\ExampleTest::test_BasicExample
This test did not perform any assertions

/var/www/parkedwrong/tests/Browser/ExampleTest.php:16

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Risky: 1.
```

.

**Can anyone explain why there are no test performed?**

.

Set Up:

```
beyondcode/dusk-dashboard  1.0.3

laravel/dusk               v4.0.4

laravel/framework          v5.7.19

phpunit/phpunit            7.5.1
```

What I have done: Searched Google, StackOverflow for possible fixes

Edit: Added the full output

Comment: Is that the whole output?

Comment: I'll edit the comment to include the full output, thank you!

Comment: Does the `ExampleTest` file like [this](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/4.0/stubs/ExampleTest.stub)?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir The contents of the ExampleTest file is exactly as the file you listed.